Should I join or split these microservices that use the same database?
I am developing an App for restaurants to manage the products they have and the orders from the customers. So I'm facing issues when designing the microservice architecture.
I thought of having one ProductManagementService and another OrderService. But the problem I am facing is that the OrderService should have access to the Products table from my database and to access info like their prices and so does the ProductManagementService for obvious reasons.
What should I do in this situation? I thought I have 2 choices:

Either sharing a database between these 2 services
or the OrderService asking every time the ProductManagementService for the products info

But I think this 2nd option would make OrderService too dependent on ProductManagementService since it'd have to call it every time an order is placed making them too coupled.
Is there any other way of making this work with different databases?
I thought of having 2 different databases with the same table synced but I don't know if this a good approach.

Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76905245?

It's always better to avoid sharing of a DB across microservices. It violates the basic charactaristics of microservices.
Your approach of having 2 different databases is good. There is a pattern called Database per service which helps to loosely coupled, scalable and independent the microservices. Also it allows you to choose different databases for each microservices.
You do not need to duplicate the tables in both the databases, just make a call to ProductManagementService API from your OrderService whenever needed.
But as in this case one service is dependant on other for information, you need to handle failure scenario's also. Like in case ProductManagementService is down, you need to implement Circuit Breaker mechanism to handle the scenarios.

If your aim is to align with the best practices and adhere to the widely accepted microservices definition, consider using two separate databases as you had already contemplated, each dedicated to a specific service (OrderService and ProductManagementService). When the order service requires product data, it should request it via API or other techniques. For further insights, refer to Martin Fowler's thoughts on data storage separation for independent microservices in the "Decentralized Data Management" section of his article: Martin Fowler's Microservices.
However, as you have observed, this approach introduces the complexity of synchronizing data and maintaining consistency across multiple data sources (a challenge Fowler also addresses).
Ultimately, this decision involves a trade-off. Consider factors such as the scale of your system, the level of granularity you want to have, and the separation of concerns you aim to achieve. If the decision to separate databases can be justified by the benefits it brings (despite the increased effort in refactoring, the overhead of data synchronization, and potential additional infrastructure costs) you can proceed with having a separate database per service.
As a slightly compromised approach, you could use a single data source but clearly define and separate the services and their data ownership. For example, the OrderService should not manipulate product data, which should remain the sole responsibility of the ProductManagementService. For more on this approach, read this article: Database Per Service or Shared Database.
